# How convert values in line c#

Tags: c#, string

input (string) : `1 2     3  4          5`

I want be :

```
string line = "1 2     3  4          5";
list<int>list = new list<int>();
list.Add(1);
list.Add(2);
list.Add(3);
list.Add(4);
list.Add(5);
```

Comment: what's the logic behind spacing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a Regular Expression to identify the occurrences of integer numbers within the text. Here's a [working example](http://regexr.com/3d6el).

This may prove to be much more reliable depending on your scenario, e.g. you could type arbitrary words/text in there, and it would still find all numbers.

The C# code to do this would be as follows:

```
List<int> FindIntegers(string input) 
{
   Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\d+)");
   List<int> result = new List<int>();
   foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(input))  
   {
       result.Add(int.Parse(match.Value));
   }
   return result;
}
```

Comment: Yes. The `@` is important, because only then the backslash is taken literally. BTW I personally find regex often too hard to read. But technically OK! upvote for a good solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Split method with the StringSplitOptions overload:

```
string line = "1 2     3  4          5";
char[] delim = {' '};
var list = line.Split(delim, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(i => Convert.ToInt32(i)).ToList();
```

RemoveEmptyEntries will skip over the blank entries and your output will be:

```
List<Int32> (5 items)
1 
2 
3 
4 
5
```

See [String.Split Method on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448(v=vs.110).aspx) for more info.

Comment: My output is from LINQPad using list.Dump().

Answer (score 0):

Try this using lambda expression and string split

```
string line = "1 2     3  4          5";

List<int> list= line.Split(" ").Where(x => x.Trim().length > 0).Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToList();
```

Comment: Wouldn't this throw an exception for each empty string that is attempted to be converted to an integer?

Comment: You don't need to trim, just split using RemoveEmptyEntries option

Comment: Super answer. Who was downvoting this !? Why!?

Comment: Not my downvote, but String.Split cannot be used in that way.... It doesn't even compile and anyway after fixing the call @bas is right. This will throw an exception on empty strings not removed from the split.

Comment: Downvoted because it 1. doesn't work (throws an exception when converting empty string to int), 2. has uncessary code (the `x.Trim()`)

Comment: @Bas thanks for explaining! I think it's better to first explain, then wait for an edit, only downvote when no edit is done.

Comment: @SQLPolice thank you for your opinion. In my opinion, it is better to verify an answer before posting it, because it puts the asker on the wrong track, especially if other people randomly start upvoting it.

Comment: Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char[]'

Comment: Updated the answer.. Thanks for everyone pointing out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the line on spaces removing empty matches with `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`.

```
string line = "1 2     3  4          5";

var list = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToList();
```

So the result will have only the numbers then you can convert to int.

Comment: `new char[' ']` creates a 32-element array full of zero chars. This does not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert multiple spaces to single ones and then split on `' '`:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(line, @"\s+", " ").Split(' ').Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString())).ToList();
```

Or directly select all numbers by one of these Regexes:

```
\d{1}   --> If the numbers will always consist of a single digit.
\d+     --> If the numbers might contain more than one digit.
```

Like this:

```
var result = new List<int>();
foreach (Match i in Regex.Matches(line, @"\d{1}")) // Or the other Regex...
{
    result.Add(int.Parse(i.Value));
}
```